# If I define the word risk as "chances of losing" what would be a word for "chances of winning/gaining"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I define the word risk as "chances of losing" what would be a word for "chances of winning/gaining"? Mere antonyms of "risk" such as "safety" are not acceptable.

*EDIT:* This question drew more attention than I expected; therefore, I feel I should have given more background of the need for this word.

In an hypothetical situation, a supervisor offers two compensation packages to a subordinate of his: one consisting of more stock, and less cash, and the other consisting of the opposite. Stocks, by their nature, carry more risks not only because of its variability in value, but also that usually there is a wait period (maturity). But it has possible advantages as well, not only because it could go up in value, but also in this hypothetical organization, employees investing more in its stock are considered to be taking ownership of it more and deemed to possibly stay longer, and thus, are more likely to be promoted. Therefore, this supervisor as he/she offering the packages, would like to say: Here they are, please weigh your risks and X's (one word that he is after)?

The first impression "risk" gives, in my opinion, is the possibility of something bad happening; or at least that is what he means. Therefore, being an eloquent person he is, he would like to say the opposite in word. Any yea, by the way, he is an ESL person :)

Comment: Not acceptable?  Why is that?  The standard terminology is risk vs. reward.

Comment: "Expectation" is the technical term for the average payback on given sized bet.

Comment: You're the one who says "antonyms of "risk" such as "safety" is not acceptable.  I was asking why not.  Also note that "is" should be "are"; "antonyms" is plural.

Comment: Xanne: I said "mere antonyms" of "risk" such as "safety" were not acceptable, because I was looking for the meaning of "chances" also. So "chances of reward" in one word would be exactly what I was after. Thanks for other correction.

Comment: @mehmet I think risk works equally well. It implies a chance of winning already as can be seen in the phrase "without risk there's no reward."

Comment: ...,,."1-risk"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for the antonym of *a word which he has made up his own definition for*.

Comment: It's possibly tainted as business jargon, but the pair of words *downside* (similar to risk) and *upside* (the antonym) are widely used and understood.

Comment: I agree with @AndyT. Risk doesn't mean "chances of losing", so the question is meaningless.

Comment: AndyT: I did not say I was looking for an antonym; now *you made up your own definition* for my way of describing a meaning that I am looking for in a word.

Comment: You weigh up the **pros and cons** of a deal or any offer. You could also say that the members of staff  need to make an [**informed decision**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/informed%20decision).

Comment: I agree, most people would say "risks" and "rewards." In the meantime, I'm not sure if I would even say something like, "Please weigh your risks and rewards." I would probably something more like, "You will have to decide for yourself which offer you prefer." I'm not saying you're wrong, just saying that it makes things so black-and-white, when I feel like a more "gray" sentence would be appropriate. But this is neither here nor there :).

Comment: @Mehmet - You *are* looking for an antonym. Your statement that you are not looking for antonyms of particular definitions doesn't mean that you aren't looking for an antonym of another definition. Your question would be equivalent to "What is the opposite of *right*, when right means *correct*; I'm not looking for the word *left*"; except that your definition isn't a valid one. In my example you'd be looking for the word *wrong* as an antonym of *right*. [FYI, to ping someone use an "@" before their name.]

Comment: @AndyT: Antonym means the opposite of a word. Even if you count "chances of losing" a word, which it is not, "chances of winning" is not opposite of it. Because one meaning common one meaning opposite. It is not total opposite. You have to justify your statement with a logical, sound reasoning.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Based on your premise, the word I believe you're looking for is "**opportunity**".

**Opportunity**: lucky chance; favorable circumstances. Dictionary.com: [Opportunity](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/opportunity)

However, for most writing involving games of chance, it is usually referred to as risk vs **reward**.  Where reward is the opposite of risk.

Comment: beat me to it by a hair. Darn that formatting. Do you have a source for your definitions?

Comment: Yep, updated with link.

Comment: In a business sense, Risk/Reward is generally used as well.

Comment: @Thomo The components of this word pair are chosen deliberately; the negative one ("risk") describes a mere possibility while the positive one describes a fact ("reward"). This pair is superior to similar word pairs like "risk" / "opportunity" because of its psychological impact on the recipient (i. e. senders from the business world with their typical incentives will rather choose the first to manipulate the recipient slightly by this into investing more). In case you want to manipulate someone into stepping down from an option, a word pair like "loss" / "opportunity" would be more suitable.

Comment: @Alfe - yep, I'm well aware of that

Answer (score 11):

If we are looking for a statistical term to mirror "risks" I think ***"opportunities"*** would be appropriate. As being ***opportune***.

> ***[Opportunity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/opportunity)***- A time or set of circumstances that makes it possible to do something
>
> ***[Opportune](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/opportune)***- especially convenient or appropriate for a particular action or event.  Done or occurring at a favourable time;
>   well timed.

Answer (score 6):

"Potential" or "Potential upside" (or maybe even "upside" itself) - i.e. "Risk is you could lose everything - upside it that it could pay-out well!"

Answer (score 3):

I would say "chance"

In your example, one might say "take a risk"

With my word, one might say, "take a chance"

Comment: but I would like to use them in the same sentence: such as both ways have their risks and Xs.

Comment: In that case, I would say "both ways have their gains and losses"

Comment: in that case they would be certain, which I don't want to mean.

Answer (score 2):

Hope.

> noun
>
> 1. the feeling that what is wanted can be had or that events will turn out for the best: to give up hope.
>
> [...]
>
> 3. grounds for this feeling in a particular instance: There is little or no hope of his recovery.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hope

Answer (score 2):

[**Expectation**](http://www.hundredpercentgambling.com/mathematical_expectation_of_a_bet.htm)

You go to a casino and bet a bunch of money.  At the end of the evening you figure out that for every dollar you bet, you won, on average, 30 cents.  Your *expectation* is 0.3

Comment: The problem with this is that expectation can be positive or negative, and the word implies nothing about whether the connotation of either is good or bad. The OP on the other hand is talking in terms of "winning" or "losing", and wants a word for the former, whilst incorrectly thinking that risk is a word for the latter.

Comment: Also just on a technical note, expectation in your example doesn't refer to the actual winnings taken in a particular sample. It refers to the average winnings that would be *expected* based on the probabilities of each event.

Comment: @JBentley - Only when expectation is greater than 1.0 is it "good".  And if expectation *is* over 1.0 for any particular gambler for any length of time then the guys in suits will probably come and escort him out.  Either that or haul the pit boss away.

Comment: On the contrary, the word "expectation" carries no information about "good" or "bad", which was my point. In your example of a casino, a positive expectation is "good" for the gambler and "bad" for the casino. The OP specifically wants a word which carries the "good" connotation.

Comment: @JBentley - But the problem is that there is no "good" in gambling.  There is "lucky", where you beat the odds in a specific case, but sooner or later the odds catch up with you.  The expectation, in any real case of commercial gambling, is never greater than 1.0.

Comment: You're too caught up with the gambling aspect. The word expectation is a mathematical term which has nothing to do with gambling - you just happened to use that as an example and I went with it. The point is that the OP specifically wants something that means "chances of winning/gaining" **as opposed to** "chances of losing". The word expectation means neither of those, because it carries no information about whether an outcome is a "win" or a "loss". Any particular value of expectation could be a "win" or a "loss" or neither, depending on the actual context.

Comment: If you look at other answers, you'll see what I mean - most carry a positive connotation e.g. potential upside, shot, hope, potential benefit, opportunity. Mathematical expectation on the other hand is entirely neutral.

Comment: @JBentley - You miss the point.  When you're gambling, in any sort of organized/commercial environment, the expectation of "winning" is **zero**, so obviously there's no name for it.  The only ways to "win" (have an expectation greater than 1.0) are 1) cheat, 2) play in a private poker game where the other players are dodos, 3) "count cards" in a casino game where that is possible.  But, as I indicated, if you attempt #3 for very long you will be escorted out of the establishment.

Comment: @HotLinks None of that is relevant in the slightest. Who cares what expectation you can get in a casino? We're talking about a word and it's meaning, and whether or not it answers the OP's question. The OP wants a word which means "chances of **winning**" and does **not** mean "chance of losing". The word expectation does not mean what the OP wants. It's as simple as that. All this talk of casinos is just a straw man argument.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you seem to think that the word expectation is fundamentally tied to gambling, when it isn't. It is a mathematical word, which *carries no connotation of winning or losing* - all it means is a long run average. The word says nothing about whether that average will be good or bad. See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Comment: @JBentley - "Winning" carries no connotation of winning or losing, except to the gambler or the casino owner, and to them it means opposite things.

Comment: ...you're still obsessed with the casino/gambler scenario, even though it is irrelevant. I suggest you re-read the OP's question - it has nothing to do with casinos. This will be my last comment; I've justified myself several times and we're just going round in pointless circles.

Comment: @JBentley - "Winning" and "losing", in the sense of weighing risks, are most easily explained in a gambling context.

Answer (score 2):

Odds.  (I think that the best answer for a straightforward question is the shortest one.  Stack Exchange disagrees.  )

Answer (score 1):

See **shot**, defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shot) as

> attempt, chance, an opportunity to do something

The good thing about **shot** is that it has positive can-do connotations, as in *I've got a shot at winning the prize*. See [take a shot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20a%20shot).

Answer (score 0):

#### Potential Benefit

Given that your example of a 'word' was actually 3 words.

Comment: :: no it was not; risk => 1 word, chances of losing=>a 3-word definition

Answer (score 0):

What to say instead of the "chances of winning":

"Odds of winning" is a phrase often used for lottery tickets. Chances are the number of tickets you purchase; each is an opportunity to play the lottery. The odds are the number of tickets sold divided by the number of potential winners. Source: see any lottery ticket or card or advertisement, and they will use this phrase.

But if the original question is actually this, "what is the opposite of financial risk?" that phrase would be either financial reward or financial security, depending on the purchase, investment, or trade being considered.
Source: investment media speak of risk vs. reward